# Portfolio images not loading in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, image, firefox

I have a wordpress website here bmfconstruction.com.au/new/ and in the project section all images are loading fine in Chrome, Opera, IE. The images are not loading in firefox at all. Tested in multiple versions. I have tried disabling all of the wordpress plugin and many things but no benefit. Can anyone help me to figure out the issue?

Thanks,
Mahendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue may be the filter greyscale.svg

So try changing this code:

```
.portfolio-item .portfolio-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    display: block;
    filter: url("grayscale.svg");
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 65%;
    position: relative;
}
```

To this code:

```
.portfolio-item .portfolio-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    display: block;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 65%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Or simply this to accommodate Firefox maybe:

```
.portfolio-item .portfolio-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    display: block;
    filter: url("grayscale.svg");
    -moz-filter: url("grayscale.svg");
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 65%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi Billy, Thanks for your help. The above codes didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it worked by using the following code:

```
.portfolio-item .portfolio-image {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    display: block;
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 65%;
    position: relative;
}
```